# Econn Reset and Heap memory out of space in node.js client connecting with elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I have a code that parses through 70 log files (each file is around 15 mb) . I extract particular fields from the log and send a bulk request to elasticsearch.  Below is the code.

```
//looks for all the files with .log extension

glob(__dirname + "/../logs/*.log", function (er, files) {
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    lr = new LineByLineReader(files[i]);
    lr.on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
    });

//each line of the file is taken and certain fields are taken from it and pushed into an array
    lr.on('line', function (line) {
        arr = line.replace(/['"]+/g, '').split(" ");
        var jsonArg1 = new Object();
        var temparr = arr[13].split("?");
        jsonArg1.url = temparr[0];
        jsonArg1.method = arr[12];
        pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg1);
    });
//once the entire file is parsed, the array is pushed into elasticsearch bulk api

    lr.on('end', function () {
        // All lines are read, file is closed now.
        data = (function () {
            var x = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < pluginArrayArg.length; i++) {
                x = x + '{ "index" :  { "_index" : "nodeclient" , "_type": "logs"} }\n' + '{"method" : "' + pluginArrayArg[i].method + '", "url" : "' + pluginArrayArg[i].url + '"}\n';
            }
            return x;
        })();

        client.bulk({
            body: [
                    data
                    ]
        }, function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(resp);
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
        });
    });
    }
});
```

The code is executing fine for around 7 to 8 log files, after that i start getting the below error repeatedly

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2016-10-28T21:09:21Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  POST http:/localhost:9200/_bulk => read ECONNRESET
      at Log.error (/home/apitestcoverage/apicoverage_node/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:225:56)
      at checkRespForFailure (/home/apitestcoverage/apicoverage_node/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:240:18)
      at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/apitestcoverage/apicoverage_node/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:162:7)
      at ClientRequest.wrapper (/home/apitestcoverage/apicoverage_node/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:308:9)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at emitErrorNT (net.js:1271:8)
```

then finally the below fatal erorr heap out of space error message appears and then it exits

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I have tried increasing the heap space in command line like below and still doesn't work

node --max_old_space_size=4096 server.js

searching about each of these errors seperately, people speak about  increasing maxSockets and reusing the pooled connections. I have no idea on doing these changes to my code.

how should i proceed to solve these errors ? are both of these errors correlated ?

Answer (score 0):

I was just getting econnreset errors using my custom bulk insert script to batch many 25-40mb files.

I increased the memory on the virtual box installation from 4mb to about 8mb and I no longer have the issue.